# Javascript regex which exclude a specific word in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have some troubles with regex, until now, I had no problem except for the following one :

I have 2 strings, I want to match with one but not the second one which contains a specific word.

```
var text1 = "The sun is yellow and the sky is blue";
var text2 = "The sun is yellow and the clouds are white";
```

It's really basic for the example but my regex was like that before :

```
var regex = /sun/g;
```

So this was ok for the text1 BUT now I want to return false the match if the string contains "clouds"
So text1 would be TRUE but not text2

I tried with (?!clouds) but I'm probably doing it wrong. It's pretty hard to use regex at this level. So I hope you could help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would do it:

```
^(?!.*\bclouds\b)(?=.*\bsun\b).*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/TYZHwS/1

Comment: Works perfectly thank you ! I'm trying to understand your code with the website you shared. If I wanted to add a "or" like "clouds|rain", I tried to use the "|" but doesn't work. Actually I don't need it but just in case

Comment: @Genki Like this? https://regex101.com/r/dJaXUL/1

Comment: Yes ! But I notice you don't use the "or" seperator ?

Comment: @Genki `^(?!.*\b(clouds|rain)\b)(?=.*\b(sun|moon)\b).*$`

Comment: @Calculuswhiz perfect ! Thank you both :D It will help a lot